# Counting the number of times an item occurs in a certain position within an OrderedDict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have made a series of functions which randomly generates scores of people based on mean performance and standard deviation.
I have written a line of code which takes the output from the previous functions and outputs the names of the people in the order of their score:

```
sortedlistofnames = [(value) for index, value in enumerate(odsailorscores)]
```

odsailorsscores being the output containing both the names of the people along with their scores already ordered.

The output look like this:

```
['Bob', 'Alice', 'Clare', 'Dennis', 'Eva']
```

What I need to do is repeat this 6 times and for each set of random values that comes in instead of just outputting the list of names 6 times I need have each position in the list numbered and added to another dictionary.

For example the entries would end up looking like so:

```
[('Alice', [3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]), ('Eva', [4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]), ('Clare', [1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1]), ('Dennis', [5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4]), ('Bob', [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3])]
```

Which would then be put back into one of my previous functions to end up as just a list of ordered names depending on their overall performance over the 6 races.

If it helps the function to generate the random scores is:

```
def scoreGen(input_dict):
generatedResults = []
for key in input_dict:
    x, y = input_dict[key]
    random_number = gauss(x, math.sqrt(y))
    generatedResults.append((key, random_number))
generatedResults = OrderedDict(sorted(generatedResults, key=lambda t: t[1], reverse=True))
return generatedResults
```

and the output looks like this:

```
OrderedDict([('Clare', 103.77155669358106), ('Bob', 100.7887661842925), ('Alice', 100.0), ('Eva', 91.8316903347015), ('Dennis', 90.0)])
```

EDIT:

There seems to be some confusion over what I'm asking which I realise is because I've written this terribly.

Basically I need a function that can take an INPUT which will look something like this:

```
OrderedDict([('Clare', 103.77155669358106), ('Bob', 100.7887661842925), ('Alice', 100.0), ('Eva', 91.8316903347015), ('Dennis', 90.0)])
```

This input is from another function which takes a dictionary which has the names of each racer and by each one has their mean performance and their standard deviation (this function is shown above), the input here is once such example of a randomly generated score for each racer using these values.

The function must be able to run 6 times and make a dictionary/list which looks like this:

```
[('Alice', [3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2]), ('Eva', [4, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5]), ('Clare', [1, 5, 3, 3, 3, 1]), ('Dennis', [5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 4]), ('Bob', [2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 3])]
```

So that this can be entered back into a function (which I have already written) which gives the overall OUTPUT of this:

```
['Bob', 'Alice', 'Clare', 'Dennis', 'Eva']
```

Which is their positions based on their score over the 6 races.

Comment: Can you actually add some input and expected output as I have no idea what you are actually wanting to count

Comment: Why are you using `enumerate()` and `index` in the `sortedlistofnames = [(value) for index, value in enumerate(odsailorscores)]` statement? `sortedlistofnames =  list(odsailorscores)` would give the same result. How does the title of your question relate to the information in it?

Comment: I have updated the question with some more information and specifics. Also that solution without using enumerate() is very helpful, I didn't know it could be that simple. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you're starting with a dictionary mapping from racer names to mean and variances of running speed. You want to simulate the results of several races and generate a dictionary mapping from name to a list of race placement results (e.g. `[1,2,1]` means that person was the fastest in two races and the second fastest in another race).

It should be easy to build the final output dictionary you want. It's entirely unnecessary to turn the ordered dictionary into a list of its keys, as you're doing in your first code block. Instead, you can directly use the `index` you're getting from `enumerate` as you iterate over it:

```
result_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

for _ in range(number_of_races_to_simulate):
    race_result = scoreGen(input_dict)
    for place, racer in enumerate(race_result, start=1):
        result_dict[racer].append(place)
```

The result will look much like your desired output, only as a `defaultdict` rather than a list of 2-tuples (but you could get the tuples if you want, by using the dictionary's `items` method).

Note that if you don't need to the running speed values from your simulated races anywhere else in your code, you could make `scoreGen` return a simple ordered list of racers, rather than a more complicated `OrderedDict` with its useless values (the code above won't need to change at all):

```
def scoreGen(input_dict):
    def keyfunc(name):
        x, y = input_dict[name] # these variables should really be given better names!
        return gauss(x, math.sqrt(y))

    return sorted(input_dict, key=keyfunc, reverse=True)
```

Comment: How did you "understand" all that from what is in the question?

Comment: Doesn't the first piece of code you showed always just print the last values? I need to be able to show the placing of each racer after each race and record that in a list as well as be able to show the overall order of the racers based on the total score after any number of races. Sorry if I didn't make that clear in the question.

Comment: @Green: I'm not sure I understand what you're asking here in your comment. The first block of code doesn't print anything, it builds a dictionary. If you need a list of names in the order the racers placed in each race, call `list` on the dictionary returned by `scoreGen` to get a list of its keys (or modify the function as I did in my second code block to return a list directly).

Comment: @Blckknght Sorry, I mean the list it build seems to just be of the position of each person the final time the list is built at the end of the loop. Also by needing a list of the names in the places they came I mean in the form of a list such as (['Alice', [1, 2, 1, 1, 3, 1], 'Bob [.... for example. The end output does need to be able to simply show the names in the order based on the totals of all of the races but it has to be done in a way that you can find out the places for each individual race if needed.

Comment: It sounds like you're running something different than what I put in my answer. My code will return a dictionary who's keys are the racer's names and who's values are lists that should have `number_of_races_to_simulate` values in them. If you're getting something else, then either there's a bug in my code (not impossible, but you'll need to provide more details) or you've incorrectly translated my code to your own system somehow. I can't help you with the latter, since I don't know what code you're actually running!